# Distance of an element to $\ker f$ in a normed vector space.

Tags: normed-spaces

Let $E$ a normed vector space and the hyperplane $H=\ker f$ with $f\in \mathcal{L}(E, \mathbb{R})$. Prove that if $a\in E$ then $\displaystyle{d(a, H)=\frac{|f(a)|}{\|f\|}}$

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/854198/any-idea-with-this-problem-of-distances).

Comment: Or, better, [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253953/distance-between-point-and-linear-space).