# Exercise regarding distance between a given point and the kernel of a particular linear functional

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Let $\mathcal{X} =\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N} : \lim x_n = 0\}$, with the sup norm, and $f: \mathcal{X} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a linear functional defined by $f(x) = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty 2^{-k+1}x_k$. The functional is continuous, with norm $||f|| \leq 2$.

Consider $\alpha \in \mathcal{X} \setminus \ker(f)$. Prove that there is not a point $x \in \ker(f)$ such that $||x - \alpha|| = dist(\alpha, \ker(f))$. I tried using the fact that $dist(\alpha, \ker(f)) = \frac{|f(\alpha)|}{||f||}$ - but to no avail.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is the $n$ in the definition of $f$ actually a $k$?

Comment: If it is a $k$ then by choosing vectors $x_n$ from $X$ with first $n$ elements equal 1 and the rest zeroes you can see that $f(x_n)\to 2$ as $n\to\infty$ and therefore $\|f\|=2$.

Comment: Why is $\text{dist}(\alpha, \ker(f)) = \lVert f(\alpha)\rVert/\lVert f\rVert$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253953/distance-between-point-and-linear-space has a nice proof of this fact.

Comment: That's very nice actually!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there were some such $x$, then $\lVert x - \alpha\rVert = \frac{\lVert f(\alpha)\rVert}{\lVert f\rVert}$.
We'd have:

$$\begin{align}
\lVert f(\alpha)\rVert
&=
\lVert f(x - \alpha)\rVert
\\&\leqslant
\lVert f\rVert \lVert x - \alpha\rVert
= \lVert f(\alpha)\rVert
\end{align}$$

In other words, $\lVert f\rVert = \frac{\lVert f(x - \alpha)\rVert}{\lVert x - \alpha\rVert}$, so the operator norm is attained.

**Hint:** Is this possible for this operator?

**Super Hint:**

> Remember that $\lVert f \rVert = \sup\{ \lVert f(v)\rVert\,;\, \lVert v \rVert = 1\}$ and consider the sequence $v = (1,1,1,\dots)$.
>
> It does not lie in $\mathcal X$, but it can be approximated by elements of $\mathcal X$. Can any $x\in \mathcal X$ do as good as $v$, with respect to attaining $\lVert f\rVert$?